# Why Regex in a while loop will match only the first occurrence length (is not dynamic in a while loop)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-core, c#-6.0

I have a regex which I would imagine dynamically captures my group of zeros. What happens is I get a list full of e.g. [00, 00, 00, 00, 00] from a string like "001111110000001100110011111"

I've tried putting my var regex = new Regex() inside the while loop in hopes this might solve my problem. Whatever I try, regex returns only the first occurrences' length of zeros instead of filling my collection with varying zeros amounts.

```
List<string> ZerosMatch(string input)
{
    var newInput = input;
    var list = new List<string>();
    var regex = new Regex(@"[0]{1,}");
    var matches = regex.Match(newInput);

    while (matches.Success)
    {
        list.Add(matches.Value);

        try 
        {
            newInput = newInput.Remove(0, matches.Index);
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }                                      
    }
    return list;
}
```

vs

```
List<string> ZerosMatch(string input)
{
    var newInput = input;
    var list = new List<string>();
    bool hasMatch = true;

    while (hasMatch)
    {
        try 
        {
            var regex = new Regex(@"[0]{1,}");
            var matches = regex.Match(newInput);
            newInput = newInput.Remove(0, matches.Index);
            list.Add(matches.Value);
            hasMatch = matches.Success;
        }
        catch
        {
            break;
        }                                      
    }
    return list;
}
```

My question is Why is this happening ?

Comment: Because you are always looking at the same (very first) match. You only execute `regex.Match` once, before you start your loop ... Your loop eventually breaks, because of the exception happening when you try to remove from an string which is shorter than your `matches.Index`

Comment: I've tried putting my regex inside the while loop but it changes nothing as I said in the description@derpirscher

Comment: You probably want to use [`regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-7.0) instead of `regex.Match`

Comment: I can only comment on the code I see. I don't know, *how*  you tried to do it inside your loop, but if it changed nothing, it was probably done wrong ...

Comment: @derpirscher I know about Regex.Metches(). I'm simply interested where my mistake lies as I can't figure it out.

Comment: As derpischer said, this is a conceptual error. Your mistake is not using regex.matcher. Its description is very clear: Searches an input string for all occurrences of a regular expression and returns all the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first approach, you are only executing `regex.Match` once, so you are always looking at the very same match until your code throws an Exception. Depending on whether your first match is at index `0` or later, it's an OutOfBounds exception (because you try to remove from an empty string) or an OutOfMemory exception (because you are removing nothing from your string but adding to your result `list` indefinitively.

Your second approach will suffer from the same OutOfMemory exception if your input starts with a `0` or you arrive at some intermediate result string which starts with `0`

See below for a working approach:

```
List<string> ZerosMatch(string input)
{
    var newInput = input;
    var list = new List<string>();
    var regex = new Regex(@"[0]{1,}");
    var match = regex.Match(newInput);
    while (match.Success)
    {
        newInput = newInput.Remove(match.Index, match.Value.Length);
        list.Add(match.Value);
        match = regex.Match(newInput);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Still, using [`Regex.Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-7.0)  is the recommended approach, if you want to extract multiple instances of a match from a string ...

Answer (score 2):

```
        var newInput = input;   //The newInput variable is not needed and you can proceed with input
        var list = new List<string>();
        var regex = new Regex(@"[0]{1,}");
        var matches = regex.Matches(newInput);

        for(int i=0; i<matches.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(matches[i].Value);
        }
        return list;
```

Comment: As I said, the problem is I don't know where my error lies and not that I can't do it with Regex.Matches(). Nontheless thenk you fgor correct attempt :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-matches(system-string-system-string)) instead of `Match` and *query* with a help of *Linq* (why should we loop, search again when we can get all the matches in one go):

```
using Sysem.Linq;

...

static List<string> ZeroesMatch(string input) => Regex
  .Matches(input ?? "", "0+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Here I've simplified pattern into `0+` (one or more `0` chars) and added `?? ""` to avoid exception on `null` string